# Quantlib; how to use PiecewiseFlatForward

Tags: quantlib

I am using the function PiecewiseFlatForward to build a curve and I am using it by setting settlementDate as an "absolute" starting date, like PiecewiseFlatForward(settlementDate, swapHelpers, Actual360()), so that the curve should be unaffected by a resetting of the Settings.instance().evaluationDate. If I change Settings.instance().evaluationDate to a date in the past with respect to the original settlementDate, the reference date of the curve stays the same, but I get an error when trying to retrieve the forward rates (unlike when using the ForwardCurve function). Here the code, where after resetting the evaluation to a past date the same forwardRate function does not work (RuntimeError: 1st iteration: failed at 1st alive instrument, pillar March 16th, 2020, maturity March 16th, 2020, reference date November 27th, 2019: 2nd leg: negative time (-0.2) given):

```
calendar = TARGET()
todaysDate = Date(25, November, 2019)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate
settlementDate = Date(27, November, 2019)
calendar = TARGET()

swaps = { 
          (6,Months): 0.028067,
          (12,Months): 0.030768,
          (18,Months): 0.029352,
          (24,Months): 0.028648,
          (30,Months): 0.028532,
          (36,Months): 0.028480,
          (42,Months): 0.028420,
          (48,Months): 0.028394,
          (54,Months): 0.028382, 
          (60,Months): 0.028387}

fixedLegFrequency = Semiannual
fixedLegDayCounter = Thirty360()
fixedLegAdjustment = Unadjusted

swapHelpers = [ SwapRateHelper(QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(swaps[(n,unit)])),
                           Period(n,unit), calendar,
                           fixedLegFrequency, fixedLegAdjustment,
                           fixedLegDayCounter, USDLibor(Period(6,Months)))
            for n, unit in swaps.keys() ]

depoSwapCurve = PiecewiseFlatForward(settlementDate, swapHelpers, Actual360())

dates = [ spot+Period(i*6,Months) for i in range(0, len(swaps)) ]

rates = [ depoSwapCurve.forwardRate(d, USDLibor(Period(6,Months)).maturityDate(d), Actual360(), Simple).rate()
         for d in dates ]

print rates

Settings.instance().evaluationDate = Date(12, September, 2019)

rates2 = [ depoSwapCurve.forwardRate(d, USDLibor(Period(6,Months)).maturityDate(d), Actual360(), Simple).rate()
         for d in dates ]

print rates2
```

Is there a way to use the .forwardRate function without having to care about the evaluation date when the function used to build the curve is the PiecewiseFlatForward?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's nothing missing in the code you posted?

After correcting for the error   `NameError: name 'spot' is not defined` (because `spot` is not defined in your code) with:

```
spot = calendar.advance(todaysDate, 2, Days)
```

it seems to work fine...